# Does "huge" and "inert" are two adjectives for "bulk"?

Tags: grammar

Does "huge" and "inert" are two adjectives for "bulk"?

IT is difficult within any reasonable compass to follow the rise of
various mediums in the United States, and a study of one or two
outstanding cases must typify the whole. The years 1874 and 1875 were
years of great psychic activity, bringing conviction to some and scandal
to others. On the whole the scandal seems to have predominated, but
whether rightly or not is a question which may well be debated. The
opponents of psychic truth having upon their side the clergy of the
various churches, organized science, and the **huge inert** bulk of material
mankind, had the lay Press at their command, with the result that
everything that was in its favour was suppressed or contorted, and
everything which could tell against it was given the widest publicity.

history of spiritualism

Comment: Are you asking if huge and inert describe bulk.? Yes!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "huge, inert" describes "bulk of material mankind".

"...the huge inert bulk of material mankind" seems to be 19th century for "silent majority".  The word "material" means those who are alive. Including that word tries to hold open the possibility that there is an immaterial mankind, i.e. the departed in the form of spirits, who are not opponents of psychic truth.